# Single word request for a plane flight which will be stopping to refuel?

Tags: single-word-requests

You have direct flights, they take you to your destination via a single flight. You also have a ___________ which stops for refuelling or for some other reason.

What is the term used for the second type of flight?

Comment: What you call a direct fllght is a non-stop flight.  The term you want in your blank is a direct flight.  I've put the references and explanations in an Answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer, according to [businessinsider.com](http://www.businessinsider.com/the-difference-between-a-nonstop-and-direct-flight-2015-9) is a ***direct flight***.  (Yes, the mind boggles.)

In its article *Here's the difference between a nonstop and direct flight*, this source says:

> You know you don't want a layover, but did you know there's a
>   difference between nonstop and direct flights? No? Well you should if
>   you want your nonstop flight to actually be nonstop.....
>
> [non-stop] flights take off at your departure city and land at your
>   destination without any stops......
>
> **Direct flights**, despite the name, will also take you from your departure city to your destination, but will make a stop elsewhere in
>   between.
>
> Some people might get off the flight during this stop, others may get
>   on, but a direct flight does not count as a connecting one as it will
>   have you staying put on the plane. Direct flights, unless otherwise
>   specified, will not have you leaving the plane, unless a plane change
>   is required, though this will usually be noted somewhere, so check the
>   fine print. These flights will be cheaper than nonstop flights, though
>   usually still more expensive than connecting ones.

If you want to know the difference between a layover and a stopover, see [usatoday.com](https://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/roadwarriorvoices/2015/08/18/the-difference-between-a-stopover-and-layover-and-why-you-should-care/83274870/), *The difference between a stopover and a layover and why you should care.*

Answer (score 6):

The kind of flight the OP asks is **"a direct flight with (a) stopover(s)"**

According to the [**Glossary of Civil Aviation**](https://airodyssey.net/reference/glossary/#a), when an aircraft stops at an intermediate airport, it's **a flight with a stopover**. It can be a technical stopover (for refueling, etc) or a stopover for embark/disembark of a few passengers. **However, it's still a direct flight** ( "a direct flight" is a flight from point A to point B without any connections, no matter whether is makes any stopover or not. **From this definition, a direct flight may or may not be a non-stop flight.** - See difference below)

If you Google for "direct flights" and "non-stop flights", however, you will find that these terms are often confused even by the print media.

The [**Glossary of Civil Aviation**](https://airodyssey.net/reference/glossary/#ss) seems to be more reliable than common dictionaries and presents the following definitions:

> - **Stopover**: Scheduled interruption of a flight at an intermediate airport, either to refuel (in which case, it is known as a “technical stopover”) or to pick up/drop off PAYLOAD (for example: flight 789 from New York to Delhi, with a stopover in London). Unlike a connection, a stopover usually does not involve a change of flight number or airline, but may involve a change of aircraft.
> - **Non-stop**: A direct flight that operates from point A to point B without a stopover.
> - **Direct flight**: A flight that operates from point A to point B without a connection. A direct flight is not necessarily non-stop.
> - **Connection**: Transfer between two different flights at an intermediate airport (for example: flight 123 from New York to Miami followed by flight 456 from Miami to Sao Paulo). If a passenger’s flights are operated by two different airlines, they may check baggage or obtain boarding passes for the entire itinerary directly at the departure city’s airport, pursuant to interlining agreements or airline alliances. *A connection is not the same as a stopover*.

Comment: Indirect flight or route is what I'd call it.

Comment: You need to add supporting references. In my experience, a stopover is usually when you have to wait for a connecting flight. / You imply that 'A flight with stopovers is a flight with brief interruptions for refueling or disembark.' is actually nentioned in your link. ???  You also need to attribute, or you might find yourself guilty of copyright infringement. Collins, I believe?

Comment: It's more complicated than TFD says.  See [usatoday.com](https://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/roadwarriorvoices/2015/08/18/the-difference-between-a-stopover-and-layover-and-why-you-should-care/83274870/), "The difference between a stopover and a layover and why you should care".

Comment: @ab2  Thanks for the link.  I'm fixing it.

Comment: I wrote an answer which says something different.  It is not clear exactly what the OP wants. (If you want to avoid all this tiresome English terminology, take a private jet.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Thank you. I've edited to provide a clear answer at the beginning.  The whole subject is confusing because there is no general agreement on the definitions.  To make matters worse, I found what looks like a more reliable source after I had answered, and then I edited.

Comment: Good edit, the post is less cluttered and the distinctions are clearer +1